# Failure in reproducing the result from the paper "ICRA2010_Marder-Eppstein"

Tags: ros, ubuntu-lucid, buiding-errors, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just started to use ROS. I am trying to reproduce the result from a paper following instructions in this link,
link: [http://www.ros.org/wiki/Papers/ICRA2010_Marder-Eppstein]

I got some errors when I was running this command:
`rosmake icra_navigation_gazebo`

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS Diamondback.

I've noticed that since the code from the paper was written in some older versions of Ubuntu(before 9.10), there were some dependency errors at first. I solved them by adding a few lines in rosdep.yaml files to specify the libs for Ubuntu10.04. But still, I got some errors.

The output in the terminal is shown here:

```
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['icra_navigation_gazebo']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/vincent/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110311-202122
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['icra_navigation_gazebo'] to:
['icra_navigation_gazebo']
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages icra_navigation_gazebo.  This may take a few seconds.
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages
[ rosmake ] Prebuilding rospack
[ rosmake ] Prebuilding gtest
[ rosmake ] Prebuilding genmsg_cpp
[ rosmake ] [ 2 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> opende >>> [ make ]
[ rosmake ] [ 2 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> ogre >>> [ make ]
[ rosmake ] [ 2 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> roslib >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< opende <<< [PASS] [ 0.03 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 2 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> roslang >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-3] <<< roslang <<<  No Makefile in package roslang

[rosmake-1] <<< ogre <<< [PASS] [ 0.03 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 3 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> pycrypto >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< pycrypto <<< [PASS] [ 0.01 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 5 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> xmlrpcpp >>> [ make ]
[ rosmake ][ rosmake ] [ 6 of 130  Completed ]
 [rosmake-0] >>> paramiko >>> [ make ]
[ 5 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> angles >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< paramiko <<< [PASS] [ 0.02 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 7 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> tinyxml >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< angles <<< [PASS] [ 0.47 seconds ]
[rosmake-3] <<< xmlrpcpp <<< [PASS] [ 0.55 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 8 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> actionlib_msgs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< tinyxml <<< [PASS] [ 0.57 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 9 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> std_srvs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< roslib <<< [PASS] [ 1.14 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 10 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> yaml_cpp >>> [ make ]
[ rosmake ] [ 11 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> rospy >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-3] <<< std_srvs <<< [PASS] [ 0.78 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 12 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> rosconsole >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< yaml_cpp <<< [PASS] [ 0.01 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 13 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> std_msgs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< actionlib_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 0.93 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 14 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> rosnode >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< rospy <<< [PASS] [ 0.49 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 15 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> rosmsg >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< rosmsg <<<  No Makefile in package rosmsg

[ rosmake ] [ 16 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> rosservice >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< rosnode <<< [PASS] [ 0.49 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 17 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> eigen >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< eigen <<< [PASS] [ 0.01 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 18 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> kdl >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-3] <<< rosconsole <<< [PASS] [ 0.68 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 19 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> roscpp >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< kdl <<< [PASS] [ 0.32 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 20 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> pluginlib >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< rosservice <<< [PASS] [ 0.53 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 21 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> rosparam >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< rosparam <<< [PASS] [ 0.57 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 22 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> pr2_machine >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< pr2_machine <<<  No Makefile in package pr2_machine

[ rosmake ] [ 23 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> pr2_controller_configuration >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< pr2_controller_configuration <<<  No Makefile in package pr2_controller_configuration

[ rosmake ] [ 24 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> cminpack >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-3] <<< roscpp <<< [PASS] [ 1.25 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 25 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> rosout >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-3] <<< rosout <<< [PASS] [ 0.75 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 26 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> roslaunch >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-3] <<< roslaunch <<<  No Makefile in package roslaunch

[ rosmake ] [ 27 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> rostest >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-3] <<< rostest <<< [PASS] [ 0.59 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 28 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> bullet >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< std_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 3.36 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 29 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> urdf >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-3] <<< bullet <<< [PASS] [ 0.73 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 30 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-3] >>> gazebo >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< urdf <<< [PASS] [ 0.79 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 31 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> actionlib >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< actionlib <<< [PASS] [ 2.60 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 32 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> topic_tools >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< topic_tools <<< [PASS] [ 1.70 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 33 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> rosrecord >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< pluginlib <<< [PASS] [ 7.86 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 34 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> roswtf >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< roswtf <<< [PASS] [ 0.65 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 35 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> message_filters >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< rosrecord <<< [PASS] [ 1.15 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 36 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> rosbagmigration >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< rosbagmigration <<<  No Makefile in package rosbagmigration

[ rosmake ] [ 37 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> geometry_msgs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< message_filters <<< [PASS] [ 0.96 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 38 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> kdl_parser >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< geometry_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 2.95 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 39 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> sensor_msgs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< sensor_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 1.71 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 40 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> tf >>> [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package cminpack written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/vincent/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110311-202122/cminpack/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] <<< cminpack <<< [PASS] [ 14.79 seconds ] -- WARNING: 30 compiler warnings
[ rosmake ] [ 41 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> nav_msgs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< nav_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 1.59 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 42 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> map_server >>> [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package kdl_parser written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/vincent/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110311-202122/kdl_parser/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] <<< kdl_parser <<< [PASS] [ 9.07 seconds ] -- WARNING: 1 compiler warnings
[ rosmake ] [ 43 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> pr2_hardware_interface >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< pr2_hardware_interface <<< [PASS] [ 0.77 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 44 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> pr2_mechanism_model >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< map_server <<< [PASS] [ 13.56 seconds ]   

[ rosmake ] [ 45 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> pr2_mechanism_msgs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< pr2_mechanism_model <<< [PASS] [ 13.84 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 46 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> pr2_controller_interface >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< pr2_controller_interface <<< [PASS] [ 4.67 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 47 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> diagnostic_msgs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< tf <<< [PASS] [ 26.84 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 48 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> amcl >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< pr2_mechanism_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 9.59 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 49 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> realtime_tools >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< realtime_tools <<< [PASS] [ 2.37 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 50 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> geometric_shapes_msgs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-1] <<< diagnostic_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 5.01 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 51 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-1] >>> pr2_controller_manager >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< geometric_shapes_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 2.80 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 52 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> mapping_msgs >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< mapping_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 9.24 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 53 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> visualization_msgs >>> [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package amcl written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/vincent/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110311-202122/amcl/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] <<< amcl <<< [PASS] [ 23.10 seconds ] -- WARNING: 3 compiler warnings
[ rosmake ] [ 54 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> ANN >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< visualization_msgs <<< [PASS] [ 8.99 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 55 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> FLANN >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-0] <<< ANN <<< [PASS] [ 13.70 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 56 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-0] >>> filters >>> [ make ]
[rosmake-2] <<< FLANN <<< [PASS] [ 13.99 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] [ 57 of 130  Completed ]
[rosmake-2] >>> point_cloud_mapping >>> [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target test_controllers
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target controller_test
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  [ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test_controllers.dir/test/test.o
  Scanning dependencies of target pr2_controller_manager
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  [ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/controller_test.dir/test/controllers/test_controller.o
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  [ 60%] [ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pr2_controller_manager.dir/src/controller_manager.o
  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pr2_controller_manager.dir/src/scheduler.o
  Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libcontroller_test.so
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  [ 80%] Built target controller_test
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/test_controllers
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  [ 80%] Built target test_controllers
  Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpr2_controller_manager.so
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  [ 80%] Built target pr2_controller_manager
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target test_robot
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test_robot.dir/test/robot.o
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/test_robot
  ../lib/libpr2_controller_manager.so: undefined reference to `boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)'
  ../lib/libpr2_controller_manager.so: undefined reference to `boost::condition_variable::notify_one()'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/test_robot] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_robot.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pr2_controller_manager written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/vincent/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110311-202122/pr2_controller_manager/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] <<< pr2_controller_manager <<< [FAIL] [ 36.78 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pr2_controller_manager. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-0] <<< filters <<< [PASS] [ 14.87 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package point_cloud_mapping written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/vincent/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110311-202122/point_cloud_mapping/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] <<< point_cloud_mapping <<< [PASS] [ 63.14 seconds ] -- WARNING: 2 compiler warnings
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package gazebo written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/vincent/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110311-202122/gazebo/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] <<< gazebo <<< [PASS] [ 158.55 seconds ] -- WARNING: 5 compiler warnings
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/vincent/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110311-202122
```

The 3 log files indicated above are:

1. pr2_controller_manager/build_output.log:

   mkdir -p bin
   cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
   -- The C compiler identification is GNU
   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
   [rosbuild] Building package pr2_controller_manager
   [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
   [rosbuild] Including /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/ros/core/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
   [rosbuild] Including /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/ros/core/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
   [rosbuild] Including /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/ros_experimental/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
   [rosbuild] Including /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/ros_experimental/rosjava/cmake/rosjava.cmake
   [rosbuild] Including /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/ros_experimental/rosclj/cmake/rosclj.cmake
   [rosbuild] Including /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/ros_experimental/rosoct/cmake/rosoct.cmake
   [rosbuild] WARNING: rosbuild_genmsg() was called, but no .msg files were found
   -- Configuring done
   -- Generating done
   -- Build files have been written to: /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build
   cd build && make -j4
   make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' make[2]: Entering directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
   Scanning dependencies of target ROSBUILD_genmsg_oct
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' [  0%] Scanning dependencies of target ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp [  0%] make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
   Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_oct
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   [  0%] Scanning dependencies of target ROSBUILD_genmsg_java
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp Scanning dependencies of target ROSBUILD_genmsg_lisp make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   [  0%] [  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_java
   Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_lisp
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_all
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile [  0%] make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   Built target rospack_genmsg_all
   [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' Scanning dependencies of target test_controllers make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   Scanning dependencies of target controller_test
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   [ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test_controllers.dir/test/test.o
   Scanning dependencies of target pr2_controller_manager
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   [ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/controller_test.dir/test/controllers/test_controller.o
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' [ 60%] [ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pr2_controller_manager.dir/src/controller_manager.o Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pr2_controller_manager.dir/src/scheduler.o Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libcontroller_test.so make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   [ 80%] Built target controller_test
   Linking CXX executable ../bin/test_controllers
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' [ 80%] Built target test_controllers Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpr2_controller_manager.so make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   [ 80%] Built target pr2_controller_manager
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' Scanning dependencies of target test_robot make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   make[3]: Entering directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test_robot.dir/test/robot.o Linking CXX executable ../bin/test_robot ../lib/libpr2_controller_manager.so: undefined reference to` boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lockboost::mutex&)'
   ../lib/libpr2_controller_manager.so: undefined reference to `boost::condition_variable::notify_one()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[3]: *** [../bin/test_robot] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_robot.dir/all] Error 2
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/vincent/icra10_navigation_ros/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/build'
   make: *** [all] Error 2

2, /point_cloud_mapping/build_output.log, shows no error.

3, /gazebo/build_output.log, shows no error.

Does anyone have similar experience or any idea about it? Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Vincent

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9387/failure-in-reproducing-the-result-from-the-paper-%22icra2010_marder-eppstein%22/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks related to https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/ticket/4383

---

Originally posted by [Paul Vernaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/240/paul-vernaza/) with karma: 181 on 2011-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-03-13**:
Yeah, that solved the problem. I followed the suggestions in that post, added that line #include <boost/thread/condition.hpp> to several .h files according to the error prompt, and it was fixed.  Thanks a lot Paul~